# TWIG / GravCMS: Use loop-variable of for-loop inside modular template

Tags: twig, grav

Here is my current code:

```
{% for module in page.collection() %}
    {% set index = loop.index %}
    {{ module.content|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to access `index` inside the `module.html.twig`, or even better, the entire `loop` variable.
How do I do that?

Comment: What is `module.html.twig`?

Comment: @DarkBee It's the module which is being rendered at each iteration of the for-loop. More: https://learn.getgrav.org/content/modular - It's basically a regular Twig file

Comment: So you want to use the `loop`-variable inside `module.content`?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, exactly!

Comment: I don't use `grav` myself but, from what I can see it's  worth a try to do the following: `{{ module.content({ 'loop': loop, }) }}` to pass the loop to your modular page

Comment: @DarkBee I found a solution by myself, but out of curiosity I also gave your solution a shot. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself:

```
{% for module in page.collection() if not module.header.visible is same as(false) %}
    {% include module.template ~ '.html.twig' with {'page':module, 'loop':loop} %}
{% endfor %}
```

This loop willautomatically grab the template which is linked to the modular page and pass the required variables down. Also, the loop will only include modular subpages which are not hidden. Great, isn't it?